# Vaadin23 access to search term entered to ComboBox from custom Renderer

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I implemented the custom `Renderer` for `ComboBox` items:

```
private Renderer<CompositeEntityResult> createRenderer() {

        StringBuilder tpl = new StringBuilder();

        tpl.append("<div style=\"display: flex;\">");
        tpl.append("  <div>");
        tpl.append("    <span ${item.name}</span>
...

comboBox.setRenderer(createRenderer());
```

Is it possible somehow to access the entered search term to ComboBox inside the renderer HTML markup? Also, what template engine is used for this markup?

**UPDATED**

```
private Renderer<CompositeEntityResult> createRenderer() {

        StringBuilder tpl = new StringBuilder();

        tpl.append("<div style=\"display: flex;\">");
        tpl.append("  <div>");
        tpl.append("    <span ${item.name}</span>
...

 return LitRenderer.<CompositeEntityResult>of(tpl.toString())
                .withProperty("name", e -> "< b>" + e.getName() + < /b>))
```

Right now it appears like a plain text in the ComboBox window, like `<b>somename</b>` but I'd like that 'somename' to be in bold instead.

Comment: This uses LitRenderer https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box/#custom-item-presentation There is no easy way to access the term. You would have to write JavaScript. What's your use case?

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to highlight the search term inside the text of ComboBox popup window

Comment: That's easy you can call getValue on the ComboBox and check if it is the same as the item name.

Comment: gotcha! One more question - how can I pass markup tags inside the `${item.name}` value?

Comment: Checkout the example https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box#custom-item-presentation

Comment: Also, I may type some text in ComboBox, but until I press Enter , the actual value of ComboBox will be null. Is there a way to get the entered text(not a value) from ComboBox?

Comment: I apologize, maybe I was not clear. I'd like to pass the `item.name` variable like for example `"<b>" +name + "</b>"`. But `<b>` tags right now appears like a plain text inside the ComboBox popup instead of bold style. How to correctly pass the tags there?

Comment: I don't understand. The example is pretty clear

Comment: Sorry again, I updated the question with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript to get the value before the user leaves the input field:

```
comboBox.getElement()
   .executeJs("return this.querySelector('input').value")
   .then(String.class, value -> { // use the value });
```

**Answer to your second question:**

```
private Renderer<CompositeEntityResult> createRenderer() {

    StringBuilder tpl = new StringBuilder();

    tpl.append("<div style=\"display: flex;\">");
    tpl.append("  <div>");
    tpl.append("    <span><b>${item.name}</b></span>
...

return LitRenderer.<CompositeEntityResult>of(tpl.toString())
            .withProperty("name", e -> e.getName() ))
```